# Proof of big-o propositions

Tags: asymptotics

I don't understand the proof of below sentences.

1. $O(f(n))=O(g(n)) \iff \Omega(f(n))=\Omega(g(n)) \iff \theta(f(n))=\theta(g(n))$
2. $f(n)=\theta(g(n)) \iff g(n)=\theta(f(n))$

How can I prove these statements?

Comment: You say you don't understand the proofs of the given sentences, but since you haven't given us the proofs, it is hard to help you with them.

Comment: All statements you quote are true, and so there aren't any "non-proving examples".

Comment: Can you prove or give some link? I cannot find the proof link.

Comment: We can't help you to understand a proof unless you tell us what the proof is.

Comment: I want proof, I edited.

Comment: What definitions of $O,\Omega,\Theta$ are you using? There are several more-or-less equivalent variants.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Also, you pose two different problems in one question; please don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be using the following definitions:

> Let $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ be a function mapping positive integers to positive integers.
>
> The class $O(f)$ consists of all functions $g\colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that for some real $C>0$, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ we have $g(n) \leq Cf(n)$.
>
> The class $\Omega(f)$ consists of all functions $g\colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that for some real $c>0$, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ we have $g(n) \geq cf(n)$.
>
> The class $\Theta(f)$ consists of all functions $g\colon \mathbb{Z}_+ \to \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that for some real $C,c>0$, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ we have $cf(n) \leq g(n) \leq Cf(n)$.
>
> We also write $g(n) = O(f(n))$ instead of $g(n) \in O(f(n))$, and similarly for the other two.

These are equivalent to the more standard definition in which the above only has to hold for large enough $n$. You can also carry out the proofs below using the standard definitions — this entails only small changes.

Let's start with the second statement: $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ iff $g(n) = \Theta(f(n))$.

Suppose that $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$. Then there exist $C,c>0$ such that for all $n$ we have $cf(n) \leq g(n) \leq Cf(n)$. Therefore for all $n$ we have $C^{-1} g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c^{-1} g(n)$, and so $g(n) = \Theta(f(n))$. Similarly, if $g(n) = \Theta(f(n))$ then $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Now let us go back to the first statement: $O(f(n)) = O(g(n))$ iff $\Omega(f(n)) = \Omega(g(n))$ iff $\Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Suppose that $O(f(n)) = O(g(n))$. It is easy to check that $g(n) = O(g(n))$ (take $C = 1$), and so $O(f(n)) = O(g(n))$ implies that $g(n) = O(f(n))$. That is, there exists $D>0$ such that $g(n) \leq Df(n)$ for all $n$. Similarly, $f(n) = O(g(n))$, and so there exists $E>0$ such that $f(n) \leq Eg(n)$ for all $n$. Suppose now that $h(n) = \Theta(f(n))$. Then there exist $C,c>0$ such that $cf(n) \leq h(n) \leq Cf(n)$ for all $n$. This implies that $cD^{-1} g(n) \leq h(n) \leq CEg(n)$, and so $h(n) = \Theta(g(n))$. Similarly, if $h(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ then $h(n) = \Theta(f(n))$, and so $\Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Similarly, if $\Omega(f(n)) = \Omega(g(n))$ then $\Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(g(n))$.

Conversely, if $\Theta(f(n)) = \Theta(g(n))$ then, as before, $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$. This means that there exist $C,c>0$ such that $cg(n) \leq f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for all $n$. Now suppose that $h(n) = O(f(n))$. Then there exists $D>0$ such that $h(n) \leq Df(n)$ for all $n$. Since $h(n) \leq Df(n) \leq DCg(n)$, we see that $h(n) = O(g(n))$. Similarly, if $h(n) = O(g(n))$ then there exists $E>0$ such that $h(n) \leq Eg(n)$. This implies that $h(n) \leq Ec^{-1} f(n)$, and so $h(n) = O(f(n))$. Thus $O(g(n)) = O(f(n))$. Similarly, $\Omega(g(n)) = \Omega(f(n))$.

Comment: It is so excellent proof I have ever seen!! But I didn't understand very trivial statement $cf(n) \le g(n) \le Cf(n)$ implies $C^{-1}g(n) \le f(n) \le c^{-1}g(n)$. Can you explain?

Comment: This is just elementary arithmetic. If you stare at it hard enough, you'll eventually get it.

Comment: Ok. sorry for my ignorance. Thank you for spending your time with me!!