# Proof involving asymptotic complexity

Tags: asymptotics

The question in [Proof of big-o propositions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90702/proof-of-big-o-propositions) asked to prove:

> $O(f(n))=O(g(n))\iff\Omega(f(n))=\Omega(g(n))\iff\Theta(f(n))=\Theta(g(n))$

The accepted answer starts the proof with:

> Suppose that $O(f(n))=O(g(n))$. It is easy to check that $g(n)=O(g(n))$ ...  and so $O(f(n))=O(g(n))$ implies that $g(n)=O(f(n))$.

I believe that there is a mistake in quoted part of the answer above.

It claims that $O(f(n))=O(g(n))\tag{1}$

and $g(n)=O(g(n))\tag{2}$

implies

$g(n)=O(f(n))\tag{3}$

Using the interpretation given in "Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS) Edition 3, page 50",  (1) is interpreted as $\forall\Phi(n)\in O(f(n)), \exists\Psi(n)\in O(g(n))$ such that $\Phi(n)=\Psi(n)$.

Additionally, the definition of $O$-notation given in "Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS) Edition 3, page 47" states:

> $O(g(n))=\{f(n):$ there exist positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that $0 \leq f(n)\leq c\cdot g(n)$ for all $n\geq n_0\}$

Considering the counter example whereby $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=n^2$. Then $O(n)=O(n^2)$ and $n^2=O(n^2)$ hold, but $n^2\neq O(n)$, thereby contradicting the assertion given in the accepted answer. Note: "$\neq$" in this case refers to "$\not \in$".

Therefore, I would like to ask if the answer provided is wrong or my interpretation and/or reasoning is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notations $a(n) = O(b(n))$ and $O(a(n)) = O(b(n))$ have different meanings:

- $a(n) = O(b(n))$ means that $a(n)$ belongs to the collection of functions $O(b(n))$. That is, $a(n) \in O(b(n))$.
- $O(a(n)) = O(b(n))$ means (in this particular case) that the two collections of functions $O(a(n))$ and $O(b(n))$ are the same. That is, $c(n) = O(a(n))$ iff $c(n) = O(b(n))$. 
   (Usually $O(a(n)) = O(b(n))$ actually means $O(a(n)) \subseteq O(b(n))$.)

Big O notation is thus ambiguous, but in practice there is usually no confusion.